# can't install libcups2-dev

Tags: drivers, printing

> uname inf: Linux N551JB 4.11.0-999-lowlatency #201704042201 SMP PREEMPT

I wanted to install drivers for my hp printer, but I got problem with libcups2-dev package. That's what installing program said:

> command: sh hplip-3.17.4.run
>
> error: Package install command failed with error code 100

I tried to install it from Synaptic Package Manager, but it refused and gave an error:

> Depends: libcups2 (=2.1.3-4) but 2.1.3-4ubuntu0.2 is to be installed

Do anyone know how to solve this problem?

Output from command: apt-cache policy libcups2-dev libcups2

`libcups2-dev:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.1.3-4
  Version table:
     2.1.3-4 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
libcups2:
  Installed: 2.1.3-4ubuntu0.2
  Candidate: 2.1.3-4ubuntu0.2
  Version table:
 *** 2.1.3-4ubuntu0.2 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.1.3-4 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages`

apt-get install libcups2 command result:

> Reading package lists... Done
>   Building dependency tree
>   Reading state information... Done
>   libcups2 is already the newest version (2.1.3-4ubuntu0.2).
>   The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
>     account-plugin-tools accountsservice-ubuntu-schemas android-tools-adb
>     android-tools-fastboot antlr3 apparmor-easyprof-ubuntu autopilot-qt4
>     autopilot-qt5 bnd click click-apparmor click-dev click-doc
>     click-reviewers-tools cmake-extras devscripts fbset gdb-multiarch
>     gir1.2-click-0.4 gir1.2-gee-0.8 gir1.2-ubuntu-app-launch-2
>     gsettings-ubuntu-schemas i965-va-driver:i386 java-wrappers javahelp2
>     junit4-doc libantlr3-runtime-java libatinject-jsr330-api-java
>     libatk-bridge2.0-0:i386 libatspi2.0-0:i386 libautopilot-qt
>     libbeansbinding-java libbindex-java libboost-dev
>     libboost-filesystem1.58.0:i386 libboost-python1.58.0 libboost-regex1.58.0
>     libboost-serialization1.58.0 libboost-system1.58.0:i386 libboost1.58-dev
>     libbotan-1.10-1 libbsh-java libbytelist-java libcapnp-0.5.3 libcdi-api-java
>     libclick-0.4-0 libcolord2:i386 libcommons-io-java libcommons-lang-java
>     libdbus-cpp5 libeclipselink-java libegl1-mesa:i386 libepoxy0:i386
>     libfelix-framework-java libfelix-main-java libfreemarker-java libgbm1:i386
>     libgeonames0 libgeronimo-interceptor-3.0-spec-java
>     libgeronimo-j2ee-connector-1.5-spec-java libgeronimo-jms-1.1-spec-java
>     libgeronimo-validation-1.0-spec-java libgflags2v5 libgoogle-glog0v5
>     libgsettings-qt1 libgtk-3-0:i386 libhtml5parser-java libhttpclient-java
>     libhttpcore-java libhud2 libicu-dev libicu4j-4.4-java libini4j-java
>     libjansson4 libjavaewah-java libjcodings-java libjcommander-java
>     libjemmy2-java libjgit-java libjna-java libjna-jni libjna-platform-java
>     libjnlp-servlet-java libjoda-time-java libjpa-2.1-spec-java libjs-sphinxdoc
>     libjsch-agent-proxy-java libjson-glib-1.0-0:i386 libjson-simple-java
>     libjsr311-api-java libjvyamlb-java libjzlib-java libkeybinder0 libleveldb1v5
>     liblttng-ust-ctl2 liblttng-ust0 liblucene3-java libmail-java
>     libmirclient9:i386 libmircommon5:i386 libmirprotobuf3:i386 libmysql-java
>     libnb-absolutelayout-java libnb-apisupport3-java libnb-ide14-java
>     libnb-java5-java libnb-javaparser-java libnb-org-openide-modules-java
>     libnb-org-openide-util-java libnb-org-openide-util-lookup-java
>     libnb-platform-devel-java libnb-platform18-java libnet-cpp2
>     libonline-accounts-client1 libpay2 libpostgresql-jdbc-java libprocess-cpp3
>     libproperties-cpp-dev libprotobuf-lite9v5:i386 libqbscore1
>     libqbsqtprofilesetup1 libqdjango-db0 libqgsttools-p1 libqmenumodel0
>     libqt5designercomponents5 libqt5multimedia5-plugins libqt5multimediaquick-p5
>     libqt5multimediawidgets5 libqt5organizer5 libqt5xmlpatterns5
>     librest-0.7-0:i386 libscope-harness3 libsequence-library-java
>     libservlet2.5-java libsimple-validation-java libslf4j-java libsqljet-java
>     libstringtemplate4-java libsvn-java libsvnclientadapter-java libsvnkit-java
>     libswing-layout-java libswingx-java libthumbnailer-qt1.0
>     libtrilead-ssh2-java libtrust-store2 libubuntu-app-launch2
>     libubuntu-location-service3 libubuntu-platform-hardware-api3
>     libubuntugestures5 libubuntuoneauth-2.0-0 libubuntutoolkit5
>     libunity-action-qt1 libunity-api-dev libunity-api0 libunity-scopes-dev
>     libunity-scopes1.0 liburcu4 liburl-dispatcher1 libusermetricsoutput1
>     libva-drm1:i386 libva-x11-1:i386 libva1:i386 libvdpau1 libvdpau1:i386
>     libwayland-client0:i386 libwayland-cursor0:i386 libwayland-egl1-mesa:i386
>     libwayland-server0:i386 libwine-development libws-commons-util-java
>     libxcb-xfixes0:i386 libxerces2-java libxkbcommon0:i386
>     libxml-commons-external-java libxnvctrl0 libxpathselect1.4v5 libzmqpp3
>     lynx-common mesa-vdpau-drivers:i386 ocl-icd-libopencl1
>     ocl-icd-libopencl1:i386 pay-service pay-ui phablet-tools python-autopilot
>     python-contextlib2 python-decorator python-evdev python-extras
>     python-fixtures python-funcsigs python-junitxml python-keybinder
>     python-linecache2 python-mimeparse python-mock python-pbr python-psutil
>     python-pyexiv2 python-subunit python-testscenarios python-testtools
>     python-traceback2 python-unittest2 python3-apparmor-click python3-autopilot
>     python3-click-package python3-dateutil python3-decorator python3-extras
>     python3-fixtures python3-junitxml python3-linecache2 python3-magic
>     python3-mimeparse python3-pbr python3-psutil python3-scope-harness
>     python3-simplejson python3-subunit python3-testscenarios python3-testtools
>     python3-traceback2 python3-tz python3-unittest2
>     qml-module-qt-labs-folderlistmodel qml-module-qt-labs-settings
>     qml-module-qtfeedback qml-module-qtgraphicaleffects qml-module-qtmultimedia
>     qml-module-qtquick-xmllistmodel qml-module-qttest
>     qml-module-ubuntu-components qml-module-ubuntu-layouts
>     qml-module-ubuntu-onlineaccounts qml-module-ubuntu-onlineaccounts-client
>     qml-module-ubuntu-performancemetrics qml-module-ubuntu-test
>     qml-module-ubuntu-thumbnailer0.1 qml-module-ubuntu-web qtcreator-data
>     qtcreator-plugin-ubuntu-common qtdeclarative5-accounts-plugin
>     qtdeclarative5-controls-plugin qtdeclarative5-gsettings1.0
>     qtdeclarative5-online-accounts-client0.1 qtdeclarative5-qtquick2-plugin
>     qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-settings-components
>     qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-thumbnailer0.1 qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-ui-toolkit-plugin
>     qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-web-plugin qtdeclarative5-unity-action-plugin
>     qtdeclarative5-unity-notifications-plugin qttestability-autopilot schroot
>     schroot-common screen-resolution-extra sqlite3 suru-icon-theme testng
>     thumbnailer-service ubuntu-mobile-icons ubuntu-push-client
>     ubuntu-sdk-qmake-extras ubuntu-ui-toolkit-doc ubuntu-ui-toolkit-examples
>     ubuntu-ui-toolkit-theme ubuntu-ui-toolkit-tools ubuntuone-client-data
>     ubuntuone-credentials-common unity-asset-pool unity-plugin-scopes
>     unity-schemas unity-scope-tool unity-webapps-qml unity8-common
>     unity8-fake-env unity8-private url-dispatcher usermetricsservice
>     va-driver-all:i386 vdpau-driver-all:i386 vdpau-va-driver:i386
>     webapp-container webbrowser-app
>   Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
>   0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 11 not upgraded.

Comment: can you tell us a little more please: you want to install "drivers" for your hp printer; ubuntu normally has hplip installed; and except for very new printers, that automatically should set up a printer  ..why do you need libcups2-dev

Comment: thank you for adding all the extra detail to your initial question; we can see more now. Which printer do you use? I ask because you are attempting to install the very latest version of hplip; and not all printers need that: eg 16.04 ubuntu has hplip already installed; eg 3.16.3